# How to get EditText value and display it on screen through TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to get the user input for the `EditText` view and display it on the screen through `TextView` when the `Button` is clicked. I also, want to know what modifications can be done on the string.xml file to do this.

Comment: can you please clarify, what do you mean by modifications to string.xml?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I didn't get the second question, maybe you can elaborate...but for your first query.

```
String content = edtEditText.getText().toString(); //gets you the contents of edit text
tvTextView.setText(content); //displays it in a textview..
```

Comment: What does getText() return if it is not a string?

Comment: It returns an [Editable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable)

Comment: To add to the confusion `Editable` is an interface and it is only because the class that implements the interface provides an appropriate `toString` implementation that this works.

Answer (score 20):

I'm just beginner to help you for getting edittext value to textview. Try out this code -

```
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editext1);
TextView tview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
String result = edit.getText().toString();
tview.setText(result);
```

This will get the text which is in `EditText` Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 7):

```
EditText ein=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
TextView t=new TextView(this);
t.setText("Your Text is="+ein.getText());
setContentView(t);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
bb.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String s1=tt.getText().toString();
            tv.setText(s1);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

First get the text from edit text view

```
edittext.getText().toString()
```

and Store the obtained text in a string, say `value`.

```
value = edittext.getText().toString()
```

Then set `value` as the text for `textview`.

```
textview.setText(value)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
yesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        eiteText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameET);
        String result=eiteText.getText().toString();
        Log.d("TAG",result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to get text from the user:

```
EditText Variable1 = findViewById(R.id.enter_name);
String Variable2 = Variable1.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Hi, other answers have the same solution, you should have read them before posting

Answer (score 1):

in "String.xml" you can notice any String or value you want to use, here are two examples:

```
<string name="app_name">My Calculator App
    </string>
<color name="color_menu_home">#ffcccccc</color>
```

Used for the layout.xml: `android:text="@string/app_name"`

The advantage: you can use them as often you want, you only need to link them in your Layout-xml, and you can change the String-Content easily in the strings.xml, without searching in your source-code for the right position.
Important for changing language, you only need to replace the strings.xml - file

Comment: Another advantage is Easy Localization.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code when clicked on the button :

```
 String value = edittext.getText().toString().trim(); //get text from editText 
 textView.setText(value); //setText in a textview
```

Hope to be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this->

EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_input);

Editable name = text.getText();

Editable is the return data type of getText() method it will handle both 
string and integer values

Comment: What does this answer provide that the others did not?

Answer (score 0):

First get the value from edit text in a String variable

```
String value = edttxt.getText().toString();
```

Then set that value to textView

```
txtview.setText(value);
```

Where edttxt refers to edit text field in XML file
and txtview refers to textfield in XML file to show the value

Answer (score 0):

**In ComposableUI, use mutablestate to read value from input boxes.**

```
class FillFormActivity : ComponentActivity() {

var nameValue = mutableStateOf("")
var emailValue = mutableStateOf("")
var passwordValue = mutableStateOf("")

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        ComposableTestTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {


                Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

                    // add top bar
                    TopBarApp(context = baseContext, "Fill Form") {
                        // to do
                    }

                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .fillMaxWidth(),
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ) {
                        OutlinedTextField("Name", nameValue)
                        OutlinedTextField("Email", emailValue)
                        OutlinedTextFieldPassword("Password")
                        SubmitButton(text = "Submit") {
                            submitForm()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun OutlinedTextField(placeHolderText: String, valueHolder: MutableState<String>) {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
    androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedTextField(
        value = valueHolder.value,
        onValueChange = { valueHolder.value = it },
        label = { Text(placeHolderText) }
    )
}


@Composable
fun OutlinedTextFieldPassword(placeHolderText: String) {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
    androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedTextField(
        value = passwordValue.value,
        onValueChange = { passwordValue.value = it },
        label = { Text(placeHolderText) },
        visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation(),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password)
    )
}


@Composable
fun SubmitButton(text: String, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
    Button(
        onClick = onClick,
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
    )
    {
        Text(text = text, color = Color.White)
    }

}


private fun submitForm() {
    val msg = "Value : name : ${nameValue.value} \nemail : ${emailValue.value},\n Pass: ${passwordValue.value}"
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show()
}
```

}

This code is working and here is output.

[image]

Happy codding.