# how to print edittext of text inside textbox line by line

Tags: android

i have follow this link [how to get edittext value and store it on textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396376/how-to-get-edittext-value-and-store-it-on-textview) its work perfectly. see this code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.feedback);



    youButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    youButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            myEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
            textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview3);
            String result = myEditText.getText().toString();
            textView.setText(result);

        }
    }); 
}}
```

i have write my name it print my name "sanjay".second time i enter "kumar" it should be print like this

> kumar
>       sanjay

3rd time i have write inside edittext "King". it should be print

> King
>       Kumar
>       sanjay

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use StringBulider and append everytime when click listener called

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            myEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
            textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview3);
            String result = myEditText.getText().toString();
            sb.append(result+"\n");
            textView.setText(sb.toString());

        }
```

Comment: but i want this king kumar sanjay 1st i have entered sanjay. this coming but after kumar the order is sanjay kumar according your code. i need sanjay should goes below every new entry........

Comment: use this 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("");

 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            myEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
            textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview3);
            String result = myEditText.getText().toString();
     String temp = sb.toString();
  sb.setLength(0);
            sb.append(result+"\n"+temp);
            textView.setText(sb.toString());

        }

Comment: hi ashish i want store o/p inside SQlite how can i do. i have read many tutorials but faild plz help......

Comment: please firstly accept the answer by clicking on right arrow below number like in your case "0"

Answer (score 1):

Write following code.

```
youButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
myEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview3);

youButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String result = myEditText.getText().toString()+"\n"+textView.getText().toString();
        textView.setText(result);
    }
});
```

**Advice**

You should not initialize any view every time `onClick` performed. Its better to initialize before that as you have done for `Button`.

Comment: Glad to help. Give Googler good notice by accept answer and up-vote if helped. :)

Comment: hi @chintan thanks for valuable reply. but what i trying 1st time the o/p should be sanjay it will be permanently. and second time "kumar".it will appear after sanjay and any name should appear like this king after kumar then sanjay reply soon.......

Comment: @user1679432 , I changed my code in `onClick`. Just have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
textView.setText(result.replace(" ", "\n"));
```

Comment: This would be for when multiple names are entered at once in the EditText. ChntanRathod's answer seems to appear to answer your question best (so far).

Comment: @user1679432 You're welcome, I had misread the first time thus the comment for clarification.

Comment: no @TronicZomB i have entered only my name sanjay. this good but next time i have entered my surname kumar. this is single world itshould be print before sanjay

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
String s = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);              
            s = e.getText().toString() + "\n" + s;
            tv.setText(s);
            e.setText("");
        }
    });
}
```

I hope this will help you.