# Retrieving and sending a Textview value from/to a Server

Tags: android, textview

I have an app with a button and also a textview (Numeric ex . 100)

i am click button then increment `Textview` (value) +5.

I am trying to send the value to Php Table Row and Also Retrieve Table Row Data in Same Text View.

in app was close and Open then fetch PHP Data(server) as per Texview

**my_table**

- id
- user_Name
- amount

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int minteger = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void increaseInteger(View view) {
        minteger = minteger + 5 ;
        display(minteger);
    }

    private void display(int number) {

        TextView displayInteger = (TextView) findViewById(
                R.id.integer_number);
        displayInteger.setText("Integer: " + number);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click the plus button to increase integer number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/integer_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="Integer: 0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/increase"
        android:onClick="increaseInteger"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="INCREASE" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="viralandroid.com"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you want to communicate with server like sending the data from the app and retrieving the data from the server ,then u want set up retrofit or volley in your  android project.Retrofit and volley are the external libraries for handling web services in android

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `TextView` & your `Button` inside `onCreate` first and remove the initialization from `display` method.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        displayInteger = (TextView) findViewById(
                    R.id.integer_number);
        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(
                    R.id.yourButtonId);

        // Here you'll need onClickListener for the button to handle if button clicked, increase the number and etc or calling methods.

}
```

Follow [Android Button Onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231309/android-button-onclick) for handle Android `Button` click.
But, the point is, if you add `onClickListener` to the Button, you may call display or just the `setText` inside `onClickListener` and no need for another method.(Simplifying)

Also add:

```
TextView displayInteger;
```

In above of `onCreate` to have access all over the `Activity` and the current class.

---

To send string to server side, follow this link : [How send data to website by using android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315415/how-send-data-to-website-by-using-android-app)

You'll need to first get the text by `getText().toString()` then sending as string to server: [How to get EditText value and display it on screen through TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396376/how-to-get-edittext-value-and-display-it-on-screen-through-textview)

Comment: I think he need more help than that! Like serializing data, making request, parsing response and also multi threading..

Comment: That's a **too broad** thread in my view. I have updated the answer for more information.