# having a problem with findViewById result

Tags: android, android-edittext, return-value, findviewbyid

I have a problem whith the result of this code.

```
private void listenbtnOK(){
        btnValider.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String cip1  =" hello ";
                String cip =findViewById(R.id.txtCip).toString();
 
                Log.d("couche presentation","*****************ok "+cip1);
                Log.d("couche presentation","*****************ok "+cip);
 
            }
        });
    }
```

Of course in the EditText txtCip I wrote "hello".
In logCat I have :

1. 06-22 13:58:12.559 ......D/couche*presentation: *****************ok hello
2. 06-22 13:58:12.569 ..... D/couche*presentation: *****************ok androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{41b34980 VFED..CL ........ 0,34-204,83 #7f0700bd app:id/txtCip}

I would like to catch "hello" in cip string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get EditText value and display it on screen through TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396376/how-to-get-edittext-value-and-display-it-on-screen-through-textview)

Comment: if you need get the text of the edit text you can do like this <br>
it is getting the object of the edit text and cast it into AppCompatEditText then you can get the text
    String cip = ((AppCompatEditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCip)).getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

Change `String cip =findViewById(R.id.txtCip).toString();` to :

```
 String cip =findViewById(R.id.txtCip).getText().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks,
getText() couldn't be resolve so I split the code.
I declare an EditText first
'''
    txtCip = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCip);
    String cip =txtCip.getText().toString();
'''
and it works.
thank you